# Opportunity Knocks and opportunity attacks

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

This is a question about timing. If a rogue character has the Opportunity Knocks feat:

> Whenever you hit with an opportunity attack ... the enemy you hit ... grants combat advantage to you until the end of your next turn.

do they deal sneak attack damage on the opportunity attack itself, or is the combat advantage applied after the opportunity attack resolves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You don't get your sneak attack dice.** Combat Advantage occurs either at the end or after the attack resolves.

> "SNEAK ATTACK
>   When you make an attack with a light blade, a hand crossbow, a shortbow, or a sling and hit an enemy granting combat advantage to you, that enemy takes extra damage based on your level (see the Sneak Attack table). You can deal this extra damage only once per turn."

Sneak Attack is triggered/happens when you make an attack against someone already granting you combat advantage. I'm not 100 percent sure if Opportunity Knocks applies the combat advantage on hit (but before damage dice) or after the attack resolves, but sneak attack seems to require the combat advantage prior to the attack roll being made.